# How can I find an input attribute's name value and then add new attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the `input` tags attribute name caled `value` and then add property checked true to it. But nothing happens.

```
 <input class="ckbx" type="checkbox" value="a"> 

 var arr = ["a"]
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   $(".ckbx").find("[value='"+ arr[i] +"']").prop("checked", true)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is used to locate a descendant of that input class, which of course there are none

You need to combine the selectors instead since they are on same element

```
$(".ckbx[value='"+ arr[i] +"']").prop("checked", true)
```

Could also use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to replace your `find()`

```
$(".ckbx").filter("[value='"+ arr[i] +"']").prop("checked", true)
```